# Magnetic field-pulsed microwave transmission line

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation

[Here's the reference](http://www.dailygalaxy.com/my_weblog/2011/08/blackholes-glow-like-a-hot-body-stephen-hawking.html):

> The researchers showed that a magnetic field-pulsed microwave transmission line containing an array of superconducting quantum interference devices, or [SQUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQUID), not only reproduces physics analogous to that of a radiating black hole, but does so in a system where the high energy and quantum mechanical properties are well understood and can be directly controlled in the laboratory.

But my problem is - I'm unable to understand the above statement . Can anyone able to put the above statements in a simple manner

Comment: If you've obtained those phrases from some reference, you can always feel free to post the link so that others may have a look ;-)